# Keeping column width in Finder

Tags: macos, mac, finder

Is there a way to keep the columns width settings?  Every time I open Finder, the columns width default back to whatever OS X's setting.[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Hold the `Option` key while resizing a column;
2. Close all Finder windows;
3. When you next open a window, the column will be the same size as you just set!

See a video [example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uW0qYbRs1zg) & also check [this](http://lifehacker.com/5686440/master-and-customize-column-widths-in-os-x-finder) useful information.

Comment: I tried but it did not work for me.